# GNUCash - can itcalculate values for new transactions based on previous entries/totals on certain accounts?

Tags: gnucash

Periodically I need to randomly (so I think this cannot be set up as  automatic/scheduled transaction) enter a split transaction with a number of splits, where the debits/credits are not static values but are calculated with a formula using certain values in certain accounts.  Im pretty sure that with the XML backend this wont be possible, but I'm thinking that with a sql backend this may be doable, maybe with some kind of stored procedure or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a python backend available which can be used to query account values and create transactions, regardless of which file type you're using for storage (xml or DB).  I'd suggest learning about that interface and see if it meets your needs.